# Backup Software that Prompts when Changes are made

Tags: backup

Here is what I want to do.

1. Hit backup and backup all my files to a jump drive.
2. Take files on the road with me and edit them on the jumpdrive with my netbook.
3. Come back to my computer and hit restore and have the files uploaded back to my computer, but I want to be prompted what files have changed and if I want to replace or keep the old file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**[Toucan](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/toucan)** - sync, backup and secure, all in one place

Toucan is freeware and portable.

of course, if you happen to have **[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)**, it will do that for you as well.

Comment: Toucan doesn't prompt.

Will Total Commander Prompt?

Comment: TC will prompt when you overwrite an existing file and you just click 'overwrite all older' so only newly created files will be copied.

Answer (score 0):

How you do this will depend largely on what OS you're using:  Windows?  OS X?  Linux?    Solaris?  AmigaOS? ;)

Another option, which may or may not meet your underlying goal, would be to use something like Dropbox ( https://www.dropbox.com/ ).  It will immediately synchronize changed files to its server, which you can access on the road, and PROBABLY synchronize with your jump drive too.

Comment: It's windows XP.

Also, this has to work with no access to internet.

Comment: You can use Dropbox when there is no internet too. It just won't update until it is online again (I think).

Comment: Dropbox free version offers you 2Gb. If your files are that small, you should use Dropbox.